# How can i stop music apps from playing when clicking a button in my flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm creating a flutter application to stop any music apps (like youtube music, gaana, spotify) from playing by clicking a button on my APP. How to implement that? Is there any built in packages in flutter to achieve this?
I have tried with a package named audio_service (https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service), but it didn't worked.

Comment: Please refer this post on Github( https://github.com/Canardoux/tau/issues/219 ) regarding the issue in Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [audio_session](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session) package:

```dart
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.setActive(true);
```

On iOS, this equates to activating the AVAudioSession and on Android it equates to requesting audio focus. If you want to be a little more specific about exclusivity/ducking behaviour, you could configure the audio session to your liking (following the per-platform documentation for each option):

```dart
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
  avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord,
  avAudioSessionCategoryOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth,
  avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.spokenAudio,
  avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy: AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
  avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
  androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
    contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.speech,
    flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
    usage: AndroidAudioUsage.voiceCommunication,
  ),
  androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain,
  androidWillPauseWhenDucked: true,
));
await session.setActive(true);
```

Note that audio_session is used under the hood in the [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) plugin to stop or duck other audio apps when playing audio.